# Where to place floating buttons to move up/down based on presented sheet dynamic height?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swiftui, ios17

I'm new to SwiftUI. I want to place a floating button on Map, but this needs to move based on bottom presenting sheet. Bottom present sheet height will be dynamic and it will minimise and maximise based on swipe up/down.

Here is the images for your reference:

[image] [image]

Here is the sample code:

```
Map {
       Annotation("", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(deviceViewModel.currentDevice.lat) ?? 0,
                                                                  longitude: Double(deviceViewModel.currentDevice.lng) ?? 0)) {
            DropPinView(deviceViewModel: deviceViewModel)
         }
     }
     .sheet(isPresented: .constant(true)) {
        MapTabSheetView()
           .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.1), .fraction(0.3)])
           .presentationCornerRadius(32)
           .presentationDragIndicator(.automatic)
           .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled(upThrough: .fraction(0.3)))
           .interactiveDismissDisabled()
     }
```

Comment: you can play with moving the buttons position/offset depending on the sheet top offset.

Answer (score 1):

You can make them a part of the `sheet` then just make the background `clear`.

```
.presentationBackground(content: {
                    Color.clear
                })
.presentationDragIndicator(.hidden)
```

Here is an example.

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
struct MapSetupView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Map()
            .sheet(isPresented: .constant(true)) {
                VStack {
                    //Buttons
                    HStack {
                        Button("", systemImage: "person") {
                            
                        }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                        Spacer()
                        Button("", systemImage: "checkmark") {
                            
                        }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                    }.frame(height: 50)
                    //Sheet
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .fill(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
                        .shadow(radius: 5)
                }
                .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.2), .large])
                
                .presentationBackground(content: {
                    Color.clear
                })
                .presentationDragIndicator(.hidden)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
    }
}

#Preview {
    MapSetupView()
}
```